# Unable to resolve dependencies (Microsoft.Asp.NetWebpages 3.2.3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget-package

This is an error I am getting when I try to install microsoft-web-helpers using Nuget on Visual Studio.

> Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.3' is not compatible with 'microsoft-web-helpers 2.1.20710.2 constraint: Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages (>= 2.0.0 && < 2.1.0)', 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3 constraint: Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages (>= 3.2.3 && < 3.3.0)'.

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the web helpers library but according to the project page it isn't compatible with MVC.  You'll have to use other packages that have the functionality you need or write your own.  I found some that may help

- Captcha https://www.nuget.org/packages/Captcha/
- Twitter https://www.nuget.org/packages/linqtotwitter